# Is there a way I can set the Tab key as (part of) an application keyboard shortcut in System Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, textmate

Basically, I would like <kbd>⇥</kbd> and <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd> to "Shift Right" and "Shift Right" (Menu items to indent or unindent selection) in TextMate.

However, I can't set them using the System Preferences GUI, as pressing <kbd>⇥</kbd> tabs to the next UI button.

Is there a way I can do that, maybe using a TextMate-specific custom `KeyBindings.dict`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `cp /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/KeyBindings.dict ~/Libary/Application\ Support/TextMate/` and add:

```
"\t" = shiftRight:;
"$\t" = shiftLeft:;
```

That would prevent expanding snippets with tab though.

Answer (score 0):

Well you might run into a stone wall there because by default the system protects and limits the functions of tab so as to ensure proper system response... System Preferences > Keyboard allows one to turn tab to be used for all dialogs in a window, etc.

That being said, are you able to (in the same Keyboard preference window) add in a custom action. Under 10.7, you should have in the right window "Application Shortcuts" from there you can press "+" and select TextMate and then select the menu action you would like to perform. Then simply enter they key strokes.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Custom application keyboard shortcuts are stored in the program's property list file in `~/Libary/Preferences`, e.g. `com.macromates.textmate.plist`.

You can assign a keyboard shortcut (e.g. by adding `Ctrl` to both) using *System Preferences* and then edit the file to get the correct keyboard shortcut (by removing `^` from the shortcut, which is `Ctrl`).

[image]

---

Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. Pressing the key combination does not trigger the menu item it's assigned to, for both `Tab` and `Shift-Tab`. The previously assign `Ctrl-Tab` and `Ctrl-Shift-Tab` work without problems.

[image]

---

So, in this case, I'm afraid it's just not possible.

Comment: @gentmatt Please make sure your formatting edits don't break the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm just trying to keep the formatting consistent here on AskDifferent. It's not nice if everybody uses different formatting in his/her post.

Comment: @gentmatt I noticed. I only commented on it since you got this one wrong.

Comment: How? Do you mean the little empty space between the lines or something else? Just curious :)

Comment: @gentmatt `^` is a character (in this context), not a key. Everything else was fine as far as I could tell.

Comment: You're right. If it were posted as a key, that edit would have been wrong. I actually wonder why apple still uses `^` instead of a compact version of `ctrl` in the menus. It's not intuitive. That `ctrl = ^` is one of the things one just has to know . Thanks!

Comment: @gentmatt Feel free to edit again. I simply reverted earlier since I don't care about your (correct) changes.